# Azure VM - join tree domain into existing forest

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

We have one machine VM01 (Windows Server 2012) in Azure. Created forest `xyz.com` in it. Synchronize it with Azure AD through Azure AD connect.

Now, we want to create `abc.com` tree domain into another machine VM02 (Windows Server 2012) under forest `xyz.com` and then synchronize it with existing Azure AD.

Tried to create Tree domain under existing forest. It gives following error in event viewer. 1908 Could not find the domain controller for this domain.

How we achieve this goal?

Comment: You can change the DNS server in the VNet to the VM01, and then just configure the VM02 with steps like on-premise.

Comment: Tried to create Tree domain under existing forest. It gives following error in event viewer.                                                                          1908 Could not find the domain controller for this domain

Comment: 1. Is the VNet for VM02 and the VNet for VM01 a same VNet? 2. Did you configure the DNS server for the VNet to be the VM01 Pravite IP address?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT  - It means add IP address of VM02 into the VM01 dns

Comment: You nearly got that. First, if you want another server to join a DC, the server needs to set the DC as its DNS server.Please refer to this document to change the DNS server of the VNet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-virtual-network#change-dns-servers

Comment: After changing it ,  VMs in the VNe needs to restart to work on it.

Comment: Yes Both vms are in same VNet.

Comment: 2.Did you configure the DNS server for the VNet to be the VM01 Pravite IP address?

Comment: Yes, I have configured DNS server for the VNet and then tried. Same Error 1908 - 1908 Could not find the domain controller for this domain

Comment: Did you restart  machines?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted both machines

Comment: Um... I did a test in my lab and succeeded. Can you `ping` the VM01 IP address from VM02 ? And try to use `nslookup` on VM 02 to check the dns server.

Comment: Yes, I can ping as well as nslookup shows vm01.domain name and IP address of VM01

Comment: Well, network looks OK. So, does the DC-VM01 work well? Try to check the DNS records on it.

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: Since you can ping it well and nslooup is OK, I think it may have issue with  the DNS records on the DC-VM01. it may don't have the domain records which you want to join.